# using socket package for octave on ubuntu

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, server, client, octave

I am trying to use the sockets package for Octave on my Ubuntu. I am using the Java Sockets API for connecting to Octave. The Java program is the client, Octave is my server. I just tried your code example:

http://pauldreik.blogspot.de/2009/04/octave-sockets-example.html

There are two problems:

1.)

Using SOCK_STREAM, for some strange reason, certain bytes are being received by recv() right after accept(), even if I'm not sending anything from the client. Subsequent messages I send with Java have no effect, it seems the Octave socket completely has its own idea about what it thinks it receives, regardless of what I'm actually sending.

2.)

Using SOCK_DGRAM, there is another problem:
I do get a reception of my actual message this way, but it seems that a recv() command doesn't remove the first element from the datagram queue. Until I send the second datagram to the socket, any subsequent recv() commands will repeatedly read the first datagram as if it were still in the queue. So the recv() function doesn't even block to wait for an actually new available datagram. Instead, it simply reads the same old one again. This is useless, since I cannot tell my server to wait for news from the client.

Is this how UDP is supposed to behave? I thought datagram packets are really removed from the datagram queue by recv().

This is my server side code:

```
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
bind(s,12345);
[config,count] = recv(s, 10)
[test,count] = recv(s, 4)
```

And this is my Java client:

```
public LiveSeparationClient(String host, int port, byte channels, byte sampleSize, int sampleRate, int millisecondsPerFrame) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
this.port = port;
socket = new DatagramSocket();
this.host = InetAddress.getByName(host);
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(ByteBuffer.allocate(10)
.put(new byte[]{channels, sampleSize})
.putInt(sampleRate)
.putInt(millisecondsPerFrame)
.array(), 10, this.host, port
);
socket.send(packet);
samplesPerFrame = (int) Math.floor((double)millisecondsPerFrame / 1000.0 * (double)sampleRate);
}
```

As you see, I'm sending 10 Bytes and receiving all 10 (this works so far) with recv(s, 10). In the later part of my Java program, packets will be generated and send also, but this may take some seconds. In the mean time, the second receive, recv(s, 4), in Octave should wait for a really new datagram package. But this doesn't happen, is simply reads the first 4 Bytes of the same old package again. recv() doesn't block the second time.

I hope it is not a problem for you to fix this?

Thanks in advance :-)

Marvin

P.S.: Also, I don't undertstand why listen() and accept() are both necessary when using SOCK_STREAM, but not for SOCK_DGRAM.